# How to check if a task with taskname is registered on task scheduler using powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0

I am creating task using powershell.
Whenever i copy a task file(not the XML one, the one which get created by task scheduler itself) into Windows Task Library and try to import the same task,it says the task already exists  .
Refer below screenshot.
[image: error thrown by task scheduler]

But you can see i just copied the file in to the task scheduler library but yet not have imported it.

So, i like to know is there any way to find out if a task is already scheduled in tasklibrary?

One way is to go through the task library path and find out if the file is present or not but as you can see someone can just copy the file task library without importing it.

Is there any way to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `schtasks /l /fo csv` and filter by the name of the task I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use "**SCHTASKS** /Query" command, it will display all the registered TaskNames with its Next Runtime and status.

Answer (score 0):

I am using one function in my scripts to check whether task is existing or not. I hope it will be helpful.

Please replace with your taskname:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.TaskName -eq "Test"}
Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName Test
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'Test'
```

You can refer this article - https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-scheduled-task/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).